# Prevent bash variables from polluting environment

Tags: bash

I have a script that compiles a .bashrc file. It tests if certain commands are available. It generates variables like so:

```
command -v cheat 2>&1 >/dev/null
HAS_CHEAT=$?

command -v git 2>&1 >/dev/null
HAS_GIT=$?
```

Other files in the script will take or not take certain actions if these variables are set.

The problem I'm having is that after .bashrc is loaded, my environment is polluted with these variables. I'd like to not have to `unset` each and every variable manually. Wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: What about ```env | grep ^HAS_```? You can loop over the results and unset them programmatically.

Comment: Ah. Not sure what the env command does but I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, a loop. Gotcha. Lemme dust of google here (bash newbie here).

Comment: ```env``` list all your environment variables for the current session. Take a look also on ```set``` and remember, ```man``` is your friend.

Comment: `HAS_CHEAT` et al. are not environment variables; they are regular shell variables.

Comment: So ```set``` is gonna do a better job then, right?

Comment: It's not clear how you use the variables in the first place, but you might be able to refactor your script by defining functions conditionally on the result of `command`. For example, `if ! command -v git 2>&1 > /dev/null; then git () { ...}; fi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the variables a unique prefix (like "`HAS_`" in the above), and then at the end run this:

```
unset "${!HAS_@}"
```

This form of indirect expansion (with the `!` and `@`) gives a list of variables with names that start with the specified prefix.

Note: I don't think this'll work in any shell other than bash.

Comment: That's a nice one!

Comment: Very nice. I'm quickly learning Bash is far whackier than Perl.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because it answered the question directly but I think @Socowi has a better approach for testing the existence of commands.

Answer (score 4):

You can encapsulate your variables inside a function and declare them as local:

```
main() {
  command -v git 2>&1 >/dev/null
  local HAS_GIT=$?
}
main
```

In your case you probably don't need these variables at all. If you have one `if`, you can write:

```
if command -v git 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
  # case in which you have git
else
  # case in which you don't have git
fi
```

If you need the status code at multiple locations I would call the same command multiple times. This may be a bit slower but `bash` isn't that fast to begin with. Also, I find `if command` way cleaner than `if [ "$var" = 0 ]`.

```
has() {
   command -v "$@" 2>&1 >/dev/null
}

if has git; then
  # case in which you have git
fi
# lots of code
if ! has git; then
  # case in which you don't have git
fi
```

Comment: This is a clean solution. I think I need the variables though because my source scripts are spread across dozens of small files. For example, I have a file for export command and a file for alias commands. They load/don't load various commands based on whether the command needed exists.

Comment: @StevieD I added another alternative for cases in which you have to access the status code at multiple locations.

Comment: Ah, you edit is a very interesting idea. I like that a lot! Lemme give it a shot.

Comment: Works great! Quick follow up. Is there a more concise way to do `if ! has cheat; then return; fi`?

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'm unsure of what you mean by *concise*. If the `!` bugs you, you can define another function `missing() { ! has "$@"; }` and write `if missing cheat`. If it's just about the length of `if ! cmd; then return; fi` then you can also write `cmd || return`. The same without the `!` would be `cmd && return`.

Comment: I got it. Had to futz with the name of the function and the return value a bit. Now I have simply: `not_have cheat && return;`. Small victories make the world a better place. Thanks a lot of this. It will make writing these scripts much more pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another possible way of doing things, you could use an associative array, which would keep everything in one place and prevent littering the namespace with a bunch of separate variables.

```
declare -A HAS=()

command -v cheat 2>&1 >/dev/null
HAS[CHEAT]=$?

command -v git 2>&1 >/dev/null
HAS[GIT]=$?
```

Then later on when you're done using these values, you can just `unset` the whole array:

```
unset HAS
```